# Comparing DataFrames in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 dataframes

df1

```
+----------+----------------+--------------------+--------------+-------------+
|      WEEK|DIM1            |DIM2                |T1            |  T2         |
+----------+----------------+--------------------+--------------+-------------+
|2016-04-02|              14|                NULL|          9874|   880       |
|2016-04-30|              14|FR                  |          9875|    13       |
|2017-06-10|              15|                 PQR|          9867| 57721       |
+----------+----------------+--------------------+--------------+-------------+
```

df2

```
+----------+----------------+--------------------+--------------+-------------+
|      WEEK|DIM1            |DIM2                |T1            |  T2         |
+----------+----------------+--------------------+--------------+-------------+
|2016-04-02|              14|                NULL|          9879|   820       |
|2016-04-30|              14|FR                  |          9785|    9        |
|2017-06-10|              15|                 XYZ|          9967| 57771       |
+----------+----------------+--------------------+--------------+-------------+
```

I want to write a comparator in spark which compares T1, T2 in both dataframes upon WEEK, DIM1, DIM2 with T1, T2 in df1 should be greater than T1, T2 by 3. I want to return all rows which do not match the above criterion with difference between T1, T2 among dataframes. I also want to have rows present in df1 not present in df2 and vice versa for the following combination WEEK, DIM1, DIM2.

The output should be like this

```
+----------+----------------+--------------------+--------------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
|      WEEK|DIM1            |DIM2                |T1_dIFF       |  T2_dIFF    | Presenent_In_DF1 | Presenent_In_DF2|
+----------+----------------+--------------------+--------------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
|2016-04-30|              14|FR                  |            90|    4        | Y                | Y               |
|2017-06-10|              15|PQR                 |          9867|    57721    | Y                | N               |
|2017-06-10|              15|XYZ                 |          9967|    57771    | N                | Y               |
+----------+----------------+--------------------+--------------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
```

What is the best way to go around this ?

I have implemented the following but do not know how to proceed after this -

```
val df1 = Seq(
  ("2016-04-02", "14", "NULL", 9874, 880), ("2016-04-30", "14", "FR", 9875, 13), ("2017-06-10", "15", "PQR", 9867, 57721)
).toDF("WEEK", "DIM1", "DIM2","T1","T2")

val df2 = Seq(
  ("2016-04-02", "14", "NULL", 9879, 820), ("2016-04-30", "14", "FR", 9785, 9), ("2017-06-10", "15", "XYZ", 9967, 57771)
).toDF("WEEK", "DIM1", "DIM2","T1","T2")

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val joined = df1.as("l").join(df2.as("r"), Seq("WEEK", "DIM1", "DIM2"), "fullouter")
```

The joined look like this -

```
+----------+----+----+----+-----+----+-----+
|      WEEK|DIM1|DIM2|  T1|   T2|  T1|   T2|
+----------+----+----+----+-----+----+-----+
|2016-04-02|  14|NULL|9874|  880|9879|  820|
|2017-06-10|  15| PQR|9867|57721|null| null|
|2017-06-10|  15| XYZ|null| null|9967|57771|
|2016-04-30|  14|  FR|9875|   13|9785|    9|
+----------+----+----+----+-----+----+-----+
```

I do not know how to proceed after this in a good way, relatively new to scala.

Answer (score 0):

One easy solution could be to join df1 and df2 with the `WEEK` as unique Key. In the joined data you need to keep all the columns from df1 and df2.

Then you can do a map operation on the dataframe to produce the rest of the columns.

Something like

```
df1.createOrReplaceTempTable("df1")
df2.createOrReplaceTempTable("df2")
val df = spark.sql("select df1.*, df2.DIM1 as df2_DIM1, df2.DIM2 as df2_DIM2, df2.T1 as df2_T1, df2.T2 as df2_T2 from df1 join df2 on df1.WEEK = df2.WEEK")
// Now map on the dataframe to produce the diff dataframe
// Or you can use the SQL to do that.
```

Comment: I need to do it on multiple columns, compute differences. Not sure if this would work. Thanks for the answer btw